# Suppose a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is nowhere monotone. Show that there exists a local minimum for each interval.

Tags: contest-math

Suppose a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is nowhere monotone. Show that there exists a local minimum for each interval.

This question is from Moscow institute. First of all, I can't even construct a nowhere monotone function. What I can think of, linear functions, clearly do not satisfy this, as we can always zoom in to get monotonicity.

Remark: A function $f$ is nowhere monotone if for every interval $[a,b]$, $f$ is not increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Definition of nowhere monotone?

Comment: This is one of those cases where you want to go about this theoretically, just using the basic definitions.  See my answer below. For examples of such functions, any continuous nowhere differentiable function will do.See for example  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to show that the set of local minima is dense in $[a,b]$, any closed and bounded interval of $R$:

Consider the interval $[a,b]$. Take $(x-\epsilon ,x+\epsilon )$ any non-empty open subinterval. Then $f$ is not monotone on the intervals $[x-\epsilon ,x]$ and $[x, x+\epsilon ]$ so we can find numbers $p,q,r,s$ such that $x-\epsilon \leq p< q\leq x$ and $x\leq r< s\leq x+\epsilon $ such that $f(p)> f(q)$ and $f(r)< f(s)$. Now $f$ has a global minimum on $[p,s]$ but neither $f(p)$ nor $f(s)$ can be this minimum. So the minimum must be interior to $[p,s]$.

Answer (score 1):

Also, OP can't figure out a nowhere monotone function. I have one beautifull example >:)

$$ \mbox{Let be }f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\mbox{ such that }f(x)=\begin{cases} x, & \mbox{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ -x, & \mbox{ if } x\notin\mathbb{Q} \end{cases} $$

such beautifull funtion, is isnt?

### [image]

Comment: also this is nowhere diferentiable