# Is it true that a non-concave function must be somewhere "pseudo-convex" locally?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

It is known that a non-concave smooth function must be [locally convex somewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028382/does-there-exist-a-smooth-function-which-is-nowhere-convex-concave).

Let me drop smoothness.

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be non-concave.

We say $f$ is locally pseudo-convex if there exists $x,y\in\mathbb R^2$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ and $f(x)\geq f(\overline{xy})$. $f(\overline{xy})$ is the image of the segment $\overline{xy}$.

Can we say that $f$ must be pseudo-convex somewhere?

The only counter-example that I can think of must be generated by Weierstrass function or similar ones. However, a Weierstrass function seems to be pseudo-convex looking at the graph.

Comment: What does $f(\overline{xy})$ mean, please?

Comment: @TonyK $f(\overline{xy})$ is the image of the segment $xy$. This is a set $\{z: \exists z'\in \overline{xy} \ \  s.t. \  z=f(z')\}.$